# Identifying New Value in Subsequent Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a historian database that I am querying using `OPENQUERY`. The query pulls back a number of fields. TS, MIN, and MAX are of particular interest. I also have access to AVG, RNG, STD, SUM, and VAR if they can be used in a solution.

The MIN and MAX values capture a state change, either from the MIN value to the MAX value or from the MAX value to the MIN value.

```
          TS          |  MIN  |  MAX
----------------------+-------+-------
09-JAN-18 16:25:00.0  | 1300  | 1930
09-JAN-18 16:27:00.0  | 1150  | 1300
09-JAN-18 16:31:00.0  |  760  | 1150
09-JAN-18 16:33:00.0  |  760  |  940
09-JAN-18 16:35:00.0  |  940  | 1240
09-JAN-18 16:37:00.0  |  940  | 1240
09-JAN-18 16:39:00.0  |  849  |  940
```

I'm struggling to write a query that can return the "new" value.

**Desired Output**

```
          TS          |  VALUE
----------------------+---------
09-JAN-18 16:25:00.0  |   1300
09-JAN-18 16:27:00.0  |   1150
09-JAN-18 16:31:00.0  |    760
09-JAN-18 16:33:00.0  |    940
09-JAN-18 16:35:00.0  |   1240
09-JAN-18 16:37:00.0  |    940
09-JAN-18 16:39:00.0  |    849
```

I could maybe do a self join and look for the current values in the previous row, but I think this would break down for example when I go from 940 to 1240 and back.

Comment: How do u like a running total, any rules on this ?

Comment: I would urge you to read this question and ask yourself if you think you would be able to provide an answer, or even understand the question, based solely on the information posted. It is not at all clear what you expect as output here. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: You should share your logic about creating "new" value...

Comment: Like.... how do you get to your desired output. The only explanation you share here is 'return the "new" value' which is not helpful. Like... why is `09-JAN-18 16:31:00.0` 760 and not 940. What is going on here?

Comment: @MaciejLos The MIN and MAX values capture a state change, a -> b. The new value is b.

Comment: You are asking how to detect *runs* in the data. From your results it looks like you want to return the row that starts a new run based on the `MIN` value

Comment: @JNevill `09-JAN-18 16:31:00.0` will only be one of two values, 760 or 1150. In this instance it is 760 because 1150 was the value at `16:27:00.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` function to get the value of a field from the previous row.

```
select ts, 
     case when [min] in 
         (
              lag(min, 1, 0) over (order by ts),
              lag(max, 1,0) over (order by ts)
         ) then max else min end
from yourtable
```

To cope with the to-ing and fro-ing issue this messier version seems to work

```
select ts, 
    case when [min] in (lag(min, 1, 0) over (order by ts) ,lag(max, 1, 0) over (order by ts)) then 
        case when [max] in (lag(min, 1, 0) over (order by ts) ,lag(max, 1, 0) over (order by ts)) then          
            case when [min] in (lag(min, 2, 0) over (order by ts) ,lag(max, 2, 0) over (order by ts)) then 
                min
            else
                max
            end
        else
            max
        end
    else 
    min end     
from yourtable
```

Comment: This is way cleaner than the `JOIN` I had imagined, but it still breaks down when going from 940 to 1240 and back.